# How do I check if the height of a div is greater than 700px, using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering, how I check if the height of a div is greater than 700px, using Jquery?

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if ($('#mydiv').height() > 700) {
    // Greater than 700px in height
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input...I wrote this and it didnt work for some reason...weird huh!

if($('#mnu_reports').height() > 700){ }

Comment: You have to put something in between the curly braces to do something.

Comment: I know that...lol...here's my code ------  if($('#mnu_reports').height() > 700){
  $(this).css('width','270px');
 } ----- Is there something wrong in the syntax?

Comment: If you're setting the same `<div>`'s width, you need to say `$('#mnu_reports')` instead of `$(this)`.

Answer (score 9):

```
alert($("#theDiv").height() > 700);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: And if you want the reference to the api, it's here: http://api.jquery.com/height/